# Cant control brightness contol after wakeup it get to max amdgpu

Tags: drivers, suspend, brightness, amd-graphics

some may think this is a repetitive question but in my case the problem its with the amdgpu driver and not with the intel graphics.

My computer its a HP laptop with ATI R5 graphics CARRIZO, The OS its Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial , the generic control works fine with every thing and the brightnes control works at any moment but i need to use the pro ṕietary driver to make run lightworks for video editing.

After installing AMDGPU controller, all runs fine unti I close the lid of my laptop or it gets in to suspension mode , after waking up the brightness or backlight its at the maximum and I can not change it via keyboard or via configuration in the control panel, it only gets working restarting the unit.

I have try all the answers in othe questions but all are intended for the Intel graphics card I have even tried those ones editing the grub and my system gets fried after that.

```
   ~$ ls /sys/class/backlight/

amdgpu_bl0
```

Thanks for your help